# Getting all repositories query Github v4 API

Tags: github, graphql, repository, github-api

I am trying to get all my repositories using the Github v4 API, but I can't find any query named `repositories`. I found a similar way to do so like this:

```js
export const query = gql`
   query repositories() {
        search(query: "user:userName", type: REPOSITORY, first: 50) {
        repositoryCount
        edges {
            node {
                ... on Repository {
                name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not what I want because I would have to provide the username which I should get through another query (and I do not want to type it by myself)

Is there a way to get all my repositories by only using one query? I think it should be easy enough, but I can't find the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the query:

```js
export const query = gql`
   query repositories { 
    viewer { 
        login
        repositories(first: 30) {
            edges {
                node {
                name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this. You can define parameter in the query and then pass them. In the example below set  `usersName` to your username and `first` to 50 or whatsoever required, keep in mind there is a limitation for `first` on GitHub API (value must be between 1 to 100 inclusive) which you can find [here](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations).

In this example if `userName` does not match any entry then an error is returned.

```
export const query = gql`
    query repositories ($userName: String!, $first: Int){
        user(login: $userName) {
          repositories(first: $first) {
            nodes {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
`;
```

You can use `search` as in your example and pass variables to the query. However, this way the query will return repositories from users those their names or usernames match or include substring of provided `searchText`. This query will not return an error if there in no match with `searchText`.

```
export const query = gql`
    query ($searchText: String!)  {
      search(query: $searchText, type: USER, first: 1) {
          nodes {
              ... on User {
                repositories(first: 50) {
                  nodes {
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

If you are only interested in your own repository then your own answer can be used as well.